# Grunt add many v= to file name

Tags: javascript, file, gruntjs, version

I'm new in Grunt (or any task manager) ;)

I have issue with filename ex: `styles.css?v=1feafc7?v=1feafc7&v=1feafc7&v=8aa4f4b`

Grunt adds me many `v=` when I run tasks many times.

I expect that it will be preserved only newest version, not all of them.

That's my `hash_res` config

```js
hash_res: {
  html: {
    options: {
        resDir: './build',
        resReg: [
          /(css\/[^.]+\.css)(\??)/g,
          /(images\/[^.]+\.(?:png|gif|jpg))(\??)/g
        ]
    },
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'build',
        src: ['*.html'],
        dest: 'build'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

PLUGIN -> [grunt-hash-res](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-hash-res)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found solution [here](https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust/issues/180)

> The problem you're seeing is because the task is processing the same
>   files over and over. It's recommended that the process for running
>   these tasks is:

`copy files to a new folder -> process files in there -> deploy that version of the code`